# Adding "<strong>" to a certain word using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, html-escape

I am using handlebars for JavaScript templating.  I want to add  around the word "success".  I would hopefully want to escape any other html or scripts in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem isn't very descriptive, but this is what I think you're after:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('strongSuccess', function(str) {
    str = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(str);
    str = str.replace('success','<strong>success</strong>');
    return new Handlebars.safeString(str);
});
```

It will first escape all of the initial HTML.  After that, you add in your own unescaped `<strong>` element, and then return a `safeString`.  Good luck :)